# CC.net and GitHub Private Repositories

Tags: git, msbuild, github, ccnet-config

Has anyone been able to figure out how to configure the ccnet source control settings to connect to a private github repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out using an array of articles and blogs online. It's actually quite simple.

1. [Setup your ssh keys without a paraphrase](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/). It's key that you do not put a paraphrase.
2. After setting up your keys in C:\Users[User].ssh directory, copy all of the contents from this folder into C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.ssh. Further information as to why [here](http://blog.analysisuk.com/?tag=/CCNET-Git-CruiseControl-CI).
3. Configure the [Git Source Control Block](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Git%20Source%20Control%20Block.html) within your cc.net configuration.

It should now work. You can setup an interval trigger, and automatically kick off your project tasks using private repositories hosted on GitHub.

Comment: When I do exactly this, the checkout hangs because it is waiting for me to supply my (empty) passphrase. Did you encounter this as well?

Comment: My issue was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835861/how-can-i-make-the-ssh-client-not-ask-for-a-passphrase-when-it-is-not-required/8836318#8836318