# How can I make the SSH client not ask for a passphrase when it is not required

Tags: git, ssh, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to set up CC.net to build from my private Git repo.

I have created a key pair, where the private key has no passphrase, and uploaded the public key to the server. I am able to do a `git clone git@myserver:myrepo` when just running it from the command prompt.

The problem is that when I try to clone the repo, I have to specify the passphrase, even though there is none. This means that I have to press enter, and this causes the automated clone to hang forever (since there is noone to do this).

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: CC.Net is CruiseControl for .NET, right? If you are using ssh-keys it shouldn't ask for password.

Comment: Propably the server don't accept login via key only. Don't know, how to configure, but maybe it helps you for searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that in my .ssh/config file, I had specified the PuTTY my_id.ppk key file instead of the OpenSSH file. Specifying the OpenSSH file instead made it work.